# Area of a triangle whose each side is less than 2 and greater than1.

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, area

What is the area of a triangle if each of its sides is greater than 1 and less than 2?

My Try:Let a,b,c be the sides of triangle,then

Area$=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{2}\frac{b+c-a}{2}\frac{a+c-b}{2}\frac{a+b-c}{2}}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}$

$1< a,b,c<2$

So  $3< a+b+c<6$ and $0< a+b-c,a+c-b,b+c-a<3$

Therefore  $0< Area<\frac{9}{4}\sqrt{2}$

Am I correct? Please also tell me some other method to solve this.

Comment: If we take equilateral triangle then since area=$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^{2}$, So we have $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$<Area<$\sqrt{3}$

Comment: So in general what it should be?

Comment: You can't satisfy all of those inequalities simultaneously, so $\frac94\sqrt 2$ is not the best upper bound. Think about the shape that would give you the maximum area if the sides were allowed to be equal to $2$.

Comment: For each side a=2,  area=$\sqrt{3}$ and for a=1,  area=$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$

Comment: Your maximum value is correct, but the shape of _minimum_ area is not an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get arbitrarily small area, since you can get arbitrarily close to the degenerate triangle $a=b=1$, $c=2$, which has zero area.

---

The maximal possible area is obtained when forming equilateral triangle with $a=b=c=2$. (I.e., the area is $\sqrt3$.)

One of possible arguments is the following:

If two sides are shorter than $2$ units, you can increase the area by leaving the third side the same as it was and changing the height of the triangle by some small $\varepsilon>0$. (Which also increases the length of the two sides, but if the change is small enough, you still can keep those lengths $\le2$.)

So it suffices to look at isosceles triangles with $b=c=2$ and $1\le a \le 2$. This means that we want to maximize the expression $\frac{a\sqrt{4-\frac{a^2}4}}2=\frac{\sqrt{a^2\left(4-\frac{a^2}4\right)}}2$. Since the function $t\mapsto t\left(4-\frac{t}4\right)$ is increasing for $t\in[1,4]$, the maximum is attained for $a=2$.